# How to fix my rotation from speeding up using Matrix4 in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I want to be able to rotate my object when I press the "x" key using a Matrix4. My code below works however, the longer I hold the "x" key, the object starts to rotate much faster over time then to start. How can I fix this.

```
var r1 = 1, r5 = 1, r9 = 1, r2 = 0, r3 = 0, r4 = 0, r6 = 0, r7 = 0, r8 = 0;
var Rx = 0, Ry = 0, Rz = 0;
var rotation = new THREE.Matrix4();

function keyDown(event){
    if(event.key == 'x'){
        mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
        Rx += Math.PI/180 //1 degree per key press
        r5 = Math.cos(Rx);
        r6 = -Math.sin(Rx);
        r8 = Math.sin(Rx);
        r9 = Math.cos(Rx);
        rotation.set( r1, r2, r3, 0,
                      r4, r5, r6, 0,
                      r7, r8, r9, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 1 );
        mesh.applyMatrix4(rotation);
    }
    if(event.key == 'y'){

    }
    if(event.key == 'z'){

    } 

}

let loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x818181});

loader.load('STL/test.stl', function (geometry) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
});

window.addEventListener("keypress", keyDown);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.applyMatrix4`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.applyMatrix4) does not set a matrix, it concatenates the new transformation to the current transformation of the mesh. Since `Rx` is incremented, the rotation wich is add increase and the rotation speeds up. Don't increment `Rx`, append the same transformation (of 1°) per key press, to solve the issue:

<s>`Rx += Math.PI/180`</s>

```js
Rx = Math.PI/180 //1 degree per key press
r5 = Math.cos(Rx);
r6 = -Math.sin(Rx);
r8 = Math.sin(Rx);
r9 = Math.cos(Rx);
rotation.set( r1, r2, r3, 0,
              r4, r5, r6, 0,
              r7, r8, r9, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 1 );
mesh.applyMatrix4(rotation);
```